# How to assign a task to a candidate group when you do not use activiti tables?

Tags: activiti, business-process-management, camunda

I have synced users from keycloak to activiti and I have `USERS` and `GROUPS` tables populated. I do not have data in ACT_ID_MEMBERSHIP,  ACT_ID_GROUP,  ACT_ID_USER tables. How can I use candidateGroup assignment to tasks in this scenario? I do not want to copy all the user data to activiti tables.

Comment: implement your own user management. follow this https://community.alfresco.com/thread/217729-separating-out-user-management

Answer (score 0):

Task assignment just stores Strings on a task (or to be more precise: multiple Strings via the IDENTITY_LINK table).
Although these Strings are supposed to represent userIds and groupNames, camunda does not really care. So you can assign to candidate group "foo" if you like.

If you want to do a task query based on users and groups and do not use the default user management (or the LDAP plugin), you will have to a) implement a custom identity service for keycloak or b) write a custom tasklist that gets all user-group relations from keycloak and uses these to search tasks via identityLinks.